# Finding out the sequence as Martingale.

Tags: sequences-and-series, random-variables, self-learning, martingales

Consider the sequence $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ of independent random variables with law $N(0, \sigma^2)$. Define the sequence $Y_n= \exp \bigg(a\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-n\sigma^2\bigg), n\geq 1,$ for $a$ a real parameter, and $Y_0=1$.

Now How to find the value of $a$ such that sequence $\{Y_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a Martingale, Sub-martingale, Super-martingale?

**My attempt**

I have generated 10 normal random variables with 0 mean and variance 4. These numbers are 1.9,4.8,-0.43,1.3,-1.5,1.5,1.2,1.1,-1.6,1.9. So i got $\sum_1^{10} X_i-4*n=-209.73$. So $Y_{10}=e^{-209.73a}$

Now, how to proceed further?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? A first step is to check for which values of $a$ the expectation $\mathbb{E}(Y_n)$ does not depend on $n$ (this is a necessary condition for $Y$ to be a martingale).

Comment: @saz, I know $X_n$ is normal random variable with 0 mean and $\sigma^2$ variance. $\{Y_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is martingale if $E(Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n) =Y_n$. $\{Y_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is submartingale if $E(Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n) \geq Y_n$. $\{Y_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is supermatingale if  $E(Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n) \leq Y_n$ for all $0\leq n \leq N-1$

Comment: Well you just copied the definitions (although some parts are missing, e.g. that $Y_n$ should be $F_n$-adapetd and integrable), but that's it. What about this particular problem? Have you tried to compute $\mathbb{E}(Y_n)$? Please add your thoughts to the body of the question rather than leaving them as a comment.